# How to customize table names for Asp.Net Identity (ex. change from AspNetUsers to a custom name)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity

I created a Asp.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) and chose the WebAPI template and Individual Accounts for Authentication. This will be the WebAPI used to authenticate users to my Xamarin mobile app.

Please tell me how I can modify the default table name in which the user information is stored when they sign up using Identity. The default name is AspNetUsers but I would like to rename the table(s) with a custom name.

Is there any migration option to update the table, or what is the best way to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `OnModelCreating` method in `IdentityModel.cs` class

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("CustomName");
        }
    }
```